# MySQL insert error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with the actual insert line.  Right now it just inserts a blank row in the table.  Am I bringing in the $email line incorrectly (line that starts with "$sql =...")?

```
<script>
function validate(form_id,email) {

   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   var address = document.forms[form_id].elements[email].value;
   if(reg.test(address) == false) {
      alert('Invalid Email Address');
      return false;
   }

<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    mysql_connect(blah) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(blah) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `email` (`email`) VALUES ('".$email. "')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
?>



}

</script>
<form id="form_id" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="javascript:return validate('form_id','email');">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is the $_POST['email'] empty?

Comment: Also read this from the official doc: "If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated."

Comment: If you don't actually have a column named `email` in the `email` table, the row will be empty every time. You're trying to insert a value onto a non-existing column. Also, better naming conventions are advised (perhaps `email_addresses` for the table and `email` for the column).

Comment: @andre: in which case there'd be no insert performed at all- there is one, but comes up blank.

Comment: So you have a table called "email" that has a column in it also called "email"? Try adding an "echo $email;" statement right above the INSERT Query to see if the $email variable is getting populated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call mysql_real_escape_string() until AFTER you've connected to the database. Otherwise you'll just get a warning and a boolean FALSE returned.

Change the order of the code to:

```
mysql_connect(blah) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(blah) or die(mysql_error());

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

This is done because the m_r_e_s() call needs to retrieve version/status information, particularly which characters need to be escaped, and this can't be done without an active DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `mysql_real_escape_string` after mysql connect.

Try set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` you will see an error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
mysql_connect(blah) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(blah) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO email (email) VALUES ('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($email));
mysql_query($sql);
}
```